# can't connect to Ubuntu 20.04.4 PPTP vpn server

Tags: server, pptp

Everything seems to be working fine but I can't connect to my vpn on windows using the built in vpn manager. here is the sys log after starting the server:

```
Jul 26 20:22:37 localhost systemd[1]: Started PoPToP Point to Point Tunneling Se                                                                             rver.
Jul 26 20:22:37 localhost pptpd[20357]: MGR: connections limit (100) reached, ex                                                                             tra IP addresses ignored
Jul 26 20:22:37 localhost pptpd[20357]: MGR: Manager process started
Jul 26 20:22:37 localhost pptpd[20357]: MGR: Maximum of 100 connections availabl                                                                             e
Jul 26 20:23:28 localhost dhclient[631]: XMT: Solicit on ens192, interval 118420                                                                             ms.
Jul 26 20:23:28 localhost dhclient[631]: RCV: Advertise message on ens192 from f                                                                             e80::250:56ff:febe:6ebb.
Jul 26 20:23:28 localhost dhclient[631]: RCV: Advertise message on ens192 from f                                                                             e80::250:56ff:fe95:48b5.
Jul 26 20:25:26 localhost dhclient[631]: XMT: Solicit on ens192, interval 128800                                                                             ms.
Jul 26 20:25:26 localhost dhclient[631]: RCV: Advertise message on ens192 from f                                                                             e80::250:56ff:febe:6ebb.
Jul 26 20:25:26 localhost dhclient[631]: RCV: Advertise message on ens192 from f                                                                             e80::250:56ff:fe95:48b5.
```